# Have Dygraph.WEEKLY labeling use Mondays as ticks in R

Tags: javascript, r, dygraphs

I'm graphing weekly data using the [`dygraphs`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dygraphs) package. `dygraphs` automatically selects a weekly default axis. However, I'm hoping there is a way to have the default axis (Sundays) line up with my data (Mondays).

```
# Required packages
library("magrittr")
library("dygraphs")
library("xts")

# Data
daily <- structure(c(4000, 5000, 3000, 7000, 2000, 5000, 7000, 
                   2000, 3000, 6000, 5000, 9000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
                   7000, 9000, 2000, 1000, 13000), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
                     NULL, c("col1", "col2")), index = structure(c(1476032400, 
                                                                   1476637200, 1477242000, 1477846800, 1478451600, 1479056400, 1479661200, 
                                                                   1480266000, 1480870800, 1481475600), tzone = "Asia/Saigon", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                          "POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "Asia/Saigon", tzone = "Asia/Saigon")

# Graph
dygraph(daily, main = "Stackoverflow") %>%
  dyRangeSelector() %>%
  dyOptions(useDataTimezone = TRUE)
```

[image: dygraph render]

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a custom `ticker` function that starts on the first day of your data and places a tick every seven days.

Here's an example inspired from the `dygraph-tickers.js` `Dygraph.getDateAxis` function:

```
dygraph(daily, main = "Stackoverflow") %>%
  dyRangeSelector() %>%
  dyAxis("x",ticker='function(start_time, end_time, pixels, opts, dygraph, vals) {
         var formatter = opts("axisLabelFormatter");
         var ticks = [];
         var t;
         //spacing is a week in milliseconds
         var spacing = 1000 * 604800;

         for (t = start_time; t <= end_time; t += spacing) {
          ticks.push({ v:t,
         label: formatter(new Date(t), Dygraph.WEEKLY, opts, dygraph)
         });
         }
         return ticks;
   }') %>%
  dyOptions(useDataTimezone = TRUE)
```

Comment: This seems to be break when using the `rangePad` argument. Any way to fix this? I would like to slightly pad the left hand side and add an extra week's datapoint/padding on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this would be reformatting `dyAxis` label values via JavaScript functions (of course, considering that the only thing you need is changing the default first day of the week).

Take a look:

```
# libs and daily object ...

# the x values are passed as milliseconds, turn them into a date and extract day and month
getMonthDay <- 'function(d) {
  var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  var date;
  if (typeof d == "number") { // value
    date = new Date(d);
  } else { // label
    date = new Date(d.toString().substring(0, 15));
  }
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  return date.getUTCDate() + " " + monthNames[date.getMonth()];
}'

# Graph
dygraph(daily, main = "Stackoverflow") %>%
  dyRangeSelector() %>%
  dyAxis(
    "x",
    valueFormatter = JS(getMonthDay),
    axisLabelFormatter = JS(getMonthDay),
    rangePad = 40 # the rangePad would adapt by itself
  )  %>%
  dyOptions(useDataTimezone = TRUE)
```

Note that we have a condition to check the `type` of the `d` object. That's because the

- `valueFormatter` - returns the [`valueOf` the date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_valueof_date.asp) object;
- `axisLabelFormatter` - returns the actual `date` itself

So, in case `d` parameter is:

- a `number` (*valueFormatter*), we simply create a new `Date` object;
- an `object` (*axisLabelFormatter*) - yes, it sends the param as an `Object`; so, we need to convert it to a proper `Date`.

The `substring()` approach is needed because dygraphs sends the object like this:

```
Sun Oct 09 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0700
```

... and, because of the 00's time, once you try to convert to a date, JavaScript will return

```
Sat Oct 08 2016 14:00:00 GMT-0300 (Local Standard Time)
```

This way, we'll always consider only the day, month and year for that. Also, you'd have the `rangePad` being applied properly:

[image]

Comment: This fails with `dyOptions(useDataTimezone = TRUE)`

Comment: Use `dyOptions(labelsUTC = TRUE)` instead, once it'll display in UTC time rather than in the local timezone. It's better for your purpose.

Comment: @dcastro this is not an option for my use case. I need local time or a solution that makes it seem like it's displaying local time.

Comment: @FrankP. got it! Please, check the updated answer. I hadn't realized that [dygraphs manipulates date objects differently for `valueFormatter` and `axisLabelFormatter`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31052300/1269558).